# Reload only the content area of a website while the sidebars remain static

Tags: 7

Is it possible to reload only the content area of my website while the rest of the sidebars remain static? I notice that twitter does this, i am wondering if it is achievable in drupal. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to update the content area without updating the sidebars using [Ajax or Ahah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). There are multiple modules for implementing ajax functionality in various parts of Drupal:

- [Views Load More](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more)
- [Ajax pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_pages)
- [Views](http://mrkadin.com/blog/node/70)
- [jQuery AJAX Load](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ajax_load)
- etc.

It will depend on the specific requirements of your site and its content as to which method would make the most sense.

Besides Ajax modules, another more advanced option is an idea often referred to as "[Headless Drupal](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/what-is-headless-drupal/)" in which you use Drupal as a backend in conjunction with a dynamic front-end framework like Angular or Backbone.

If you're just getting started with Drupal though, I would encourage you to get a bit of experience building simple Drupal sites before getting too focused on Ajax functionality. If you're not already familiar with Javascript, you'll likely end up being somewhat limited in terms of what you can do with the out-of-the-box functionality available from community contributed modules.